# Implementing 301 redirects in sub-folder of Silverstripe

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, silverstripe

I am trying to create 301 redirects from a silverstripe subdirectory to a new site/subdomain on different server, can't seem to make it work!

So need www.researchnutrition.com.au/practitioner redirecting to www.practitioner.researchnutrition.com.au
along with a number of other urls within the practitioner subfolder specified to new pages on new domain.

Have tried several combinations or rewrite/redirect rules but nothing seems to be taking effect.

Also should the .htaccess file where I make the changes need to sit within the root folder or within the /practitioner folder.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.htaccess` file in the `practitioner` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.practitioner.researchnutrition.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Croises - has worked for certain pages but not all. A bit confusing, especially not if page names are different from old site! eg. Want to redirect www.researchnutrition.com.au/practitioner/upcoming-events to www.practitioner.researchnutrition.com.au/upcoming-events - I have added in .htacess file in /practitioner folder: Redirect 301 /upcoming-events http://www.practitioner.researchnutrition.com.au/education/upcoming-events
Here's the redirect url: that I end up in the browser: http://www.practitioner.researchnutrition.com.auupcoming-events/?url=/practitioner/upcoming-events/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just creating a redirection page in the cms and redirecting that to an external url (which is, despite the option saying "redirect to internal page", possible).

Comment: Hmm...hadn't thought of this one, although right not the old /admin login is redirecting to new site admin! I guess in due course the old CMS and site will be taken down though but maybe by then Google would've reindexed. I'll see how I go. Thanks for your suggestion @jberculo.

Comment: You could do a combination of both. Use htaccess to redirect all, and if the name has changed, add an internal redirect. These pages will be redirected twice then, which means a little extra SEO loss, but in most cases this does not really matter.